# Detail the big-O of Hashmap - put() method by real code in Java 8

Tags: java, big-o

I 'm novice in Algorithm. I read and aware that big-O of put(K key, V value) in Hashmap is O(1).
When I went to core of HashMap class

```
    final V putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent,
               boolean evict) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> p; int n, i;
    if ((tab = table) == null || (n = tab.length) == 0)
        //...
    if ((p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) == null)
        //...
    else {
        Node<K,V> e; K k;
        if (p.hash == hash &&
            ((k = p.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            e = p;
        else if (p instanceof TreeNode)
            // ...
        else {
            for (int binCount = 0; ; ++binCount) {
                if ((e = p.next) == null) {
                    p.next = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
                    // ...
                }
                if (e.hash == hash &&
                    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                    break;
                p = e;
            }
        }
        if (e != null) { // existing mapping for key
           // ...
        }
    }
    ...
    return null;
}
```

As you can see, when adding **new** item to hashmap, it will iterate max n (all item in hashmap) with "For Loop" above:

```
 for (int binCount = 0; ; ++binCount) {
```

Now, big-O of For Loop here is O(n) --> Why big-O of put(K key, V value) in HashMap can be O(1) ?
Where do I understand wrongly ?

Thanks very much.

Comment: why are you posting the exact same question twice? Your first one already has been closed as duplicate

Answer (score 3):

The HashMap is actually a collection (backed by an array) of buckets that are backed by a Red-Black tree (as of Java 8).  If you have a very poor hashing function that puts all the elements into the same bin, then performance would degrade to `O(log(n))`

From [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collections-interview-questions),

> HashMap has O(1) complexity, or constant-time complexity, of putting and getting the elements. Of course, lots of collisions could degrade the performance to O(log(n)) time complexity in the worst case, when all elements land in a single bucket. This is usually solved by providing a good hash function with a uniform distribution.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html),

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that a single bin of the hash table has an expected constant number of elements. Therefore the loop you mentioned would run in O(1) expected time (assuming the `hashCode()` of your keys is not terrible).

Specifically, for the `HashMap` implementation, there's a load factor whose value is 0.75 by default. This means that on average, each bin of the `HashMap` should have <= 0.75 elements (once there are more than load-factor * number-of-bins entries in the `HashMap`, the number-of-bins is doubled in order to maintain this invariant). Therefore, the mentioned loop should have a single iteration on average.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O notation has to do with the performance of a function relative to the number of elements is operates on.  Just having a for loop doesn't suddenly make a `Hashmap` lookup's performance grow by a fixed amount for every element within the `Hashmap`.

There are patterns in Big-O notation.  Loops across the entire set of elements is `O(n)` but loops in general don't mean the lookup is `O(n)`.  To illustrate, I'll use the (silly) example below

Function with `O(1)` performance

```
  public void add_o_one(int x, int y) {
     return x + y;
  }
```

Function with `O(1)` performance, with loops added

```
  public void add_still_o_one(int x, int y) {
     int[2] numbers;
     numbers[0] = x; 
     numbers[1] = y;
     int result = 0;
     for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
        result += numbers[index];
     }
     return result;
  }
```

While I would expect the latter one to be a bit less efficient, there's no way to alter its run-time speed by choosing different (or more) numbers.  Therefore, it is still `O(1)`.

In your Hashmap, the looping over bucket lists does alter the speed relative to the input; but, it doesn't alter it by a constant amount for each element.  Also, most of the hashmap implementations grow their bucket size as the map fills.  This means that what you are seeing is not a common case, and is likely to seldom be called (unless you implement a really bad hashcode).

While you might consider that "something larger than `O(1)`" it is very difficult to make the code function in a way that is inconsistent with `O(1)` unless you specifically break the algorithm (by providing objects that all hash to the same value, for example).